# The ref property of an open graph action have no effect on app insights

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-insights

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/

in the Opengraph actions docs there is an Optional Parameters: ref property, that suppose to help with A/B testing by:

> By default, the ref parameter will accept 500 unique values for ref in
>   a 7 day period. These values will be used to display graphs grouped by
>   each unique value of ref in your application's insights.

I've start using it, i see that the ref property saved for my actions view graph API and i have have the fb_ref in the actions links, but i don't see any "graphs grouped by each unique value of ref"
Did i understand it wrong or could be its isn't implemented?

Thanks,
Bnaya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the Ref Parameter values on the insights under Open Graph  ›  Demographics.
It's a shame its not documented well.